# In Google Cloud Scheduler, is there a way to set the time zone to Europe/Berlin?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, timezone, timezone-offset, google-cloud-scheduler

(see note below WRT the terminology)

I'd like to have a cron job run at 00:00, 04:00, 08:00, ... in the Europe/Berlin time zone. I'm using this frequency configuration: "0 */4 * * *". However, I cannot find a way to set the time zone to Europe/Berlin. The "Timezone" drop-down has entries for CET (UTC+1) and CEST (UTC+2), but neither of them is correct for Europe/Berlin the whole year. I obviously do NOT want to change this setting twice a year. Is there a way to change this setting to Europe/Berlin? That one does not seem to appear in the drop-down at all.

I am aware that I could change the configuration to "every hour" and check the actual condition in the code called by the scheduler, but that would be ugly in multiple ways and is certainly not the point of the frequency being configurable.

Note WRT terminology: I could not find out whether "time zone" is actually the correct term to use for a geographical location such as Europe/Berlin, or for a fixed offset from UTC such as CET (UTC+1), or both. Nor could I find out what the correct terms for the other things are. Documentation on the web in general doesn't even make a distinction, and for Cloud Scheduler specifically I wasn't able to find the relevant documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand your issue. I tried to create a scheduler with the UI, I selected the country of my timezone (Germany) then Berlin, and it worked well (even if in the field it's mentioned CEST

I also tested with the CLI, and it worked perfectly

```
gcloud scheduler jobs create http --time-zone=Europe/Berlin \
 --uri='https://www.google.com' --location=europe-west1 --schedule="0 0 1 1 0" by-cli
```

Here the UI result
[image]

Comment: Germany does not even appear in the Drop-Down. However, when you filter by "Germany", it appears (don't know why), and below that you can select CEST, which is not what I want (as described). Do you mean that by selecting CEST there, I'm not actually selecting CEST but Germany?

Comment: Update: I created a new test job where I did select CEST in the drop-down. The overview then showed Europe/Berlin, even though I selected CEST. When I went into the editor again, it did not show Europe/Berlin as in the overview, but CEST again. I have to admit that I stopped understanding anything about this setting, and this makes me seriously doubt that it will work reliably when we switch back to CET next winter...